# Store the value entered in apex:inlineeditsupport to an apex variable

Tags: apex, visualforce, inlineeditsupport

I have a requirement where I need to assign the value entered in `apex:inlineeditsupport` to a variable on the page everytime that `inlineedit` support tag is double clicked and edited. Is it possible to assign it to an `apex:variable`? Can anyone give me a simplified example as to how it can be done.

Actually I want to capture the value of the field after `inlinedit` has been done an before it has been saved in the database. Depending on that a alert is to be displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use inlineEdit support with `apex:outputField`..

```
<apex:outputField value="{!customerObj.Address__c}">
      <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveButton" event="ondblclick"/>    
</apex:outputField>
```

---

TO get the inline Edit value use like this.

**Wrap your inline Edit inside a div and give a class name**

```
<div Class="tdData">
   <apex:pageBlockSection >
       <apex:outputField value="{!contact.lastname}">
            <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveButton, cancelButton" 
                            hideOnEdit="editButton" event="ondblclick" 
                            changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/>
       </apex:outputField>

    <apex:outputField value="{!contact.accountId}"/>
    <apex:outputField value="{!contact.phone}"/>
  </apex:pageBlockSection>
</div>
```

And srcipt

```
<apex:includeScript value="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"/>
        <script>
          $(document).ready(function() {
              $('.tdData :hidden').change(function(e) {
                 alert(e.target.value);
            });
          });
        </script>
```

Now when inside `tdData` class inside hidden value updated this script will execute and we can check the value in alert.

**Complete code**.. I have tested below code.

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton action="{!edit}" id="editButton" value="Edit"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" id="saveButton" value="Save"/>
                <apex:commandButton onclick="resetInlineEdit()" id="cancelButton" value="Cancel"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>

            <div Class="tdData">
                <apex:pageBlockSection >
                    <apex:outputField value="{!contact.lastname}">
                        <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveButton, cancelButton" 
                            hideOnEdit="editButton" event="ondblclick" 
                            changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/>
                    </apex:outputField>

                    <apex:outputField value="{!contact.accountId}"/>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!contact.phone}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </div>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:includeScript value="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"/>
        <script>
          $(document).ready(function() {
              $('.tdData :hidden').change(function(e) {
                 alert(e.target.value);
            });
          });
        </script>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Actually I want to capture the value of the field after inlinedit has been done an before it has been saven in the database. Depending on that a alert is to be displayed. @Ratan

Comment: @Rimii I don't this you can do that.. You can check the value using javscript or in controller side..  How you are saving the data in database.. using any DML in controller side? if yes then check value in controller

Comment: @Rimii can't we check the value in controller side ?

Comment: We can't. My requirement is that if that particular field has been entered a null value, an alert is to be displayed. The alert is displayed on savebutton click depending on whether a null value has been entered. It will display the alert but would not save the null value

Comment: @Rimii check my updated ans.. You can use jquery to bind the change event whenever inline support change the value javascript function will be called there we can check the value.. I suggest try to create new page then check my complete code how that works. and it will work for you or not..

Comment: I am working on that. Your version is working. I am trying to incorporate it to my requirement. I will accept your answer once it is done.

Comment: @Rimii cool.. It helped you..

Comment: I had a question regarding this. Here I you are using the div to call the javascript method. Is it possible to call the method on save button click @Ratan

Comment: @Rimii then on save button call a javascript and there check all the values.. if all the values good then call controller method